# processing request parameters in google Oauth2.0

Tags: java, servlets, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use Google OAuth2.0 authentication mechanism in my java web application. However, I am having some basic challenges doing so for which I am seeking help here -

I have registered my application in Google API Console and login url redirected to my localhost application for developing purpose. After the user authenticating the application, the I am trying to process the access token provided by the google in a servlet - but however, I am seeing the url coming from google as below -

`http: //local host:8080//loginProcess#access_token=ya29.AHS6ZQBN-4Snrj6P9i4xPxbCxLLkmbPf3Jc2Dj7eUA72FWIy4&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`

servlet name being "loginProcess", please observe # after it - with hash being in the request parameters, I am not able to retrieve them in the java servlet using request.getParameter("access_token");

I hope I am clear in my question - if not, please let me know the details that I am missing..

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: it should be question mark(?) instead of # after loginProcess, so you can retrieve the value as request parameter.

Comment: That's absolutely right! But, this is what I am getting from Google. So, my question is - how should I parse the request parameters that are staring with '#' and not '?'

Comment: you can do one thing here.It is a tweak only.Try to get its request URL , like this.request.getRequestURL().toString().And check the first occurrence of either '#' or '?' depending upon their existences, you can retrieve the value of the token.

Comment: Thank you Unni V Mana for your responses - I have tried this but I get the string only upto the servlet name, i.e. httP:// www.localhost:8080/ loginProcess,  thats it. I am not having the complete string with request parameters

Comment: how it is localhost if it is returning from google?

Comment: I have registered my web app with Google APIs Console, with redirect url as my localhost servlet url. Hence, google is supposed to send me the access tokens to my local url. But, I am having issues as to how can I process the request parameters starting with #, instead of ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour for *client-side applications* (JavaScript running in a browser). I don't know if this is your actual scenario, if so, to handle the response, *javascript* is your only option, as from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#handlingtheresponse)

---

If not, probably you need to change your authorization request (scenario) to [*Web Server applications*](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer), in this case you are allowed to handle the response using the `request.getParameter("access_token")`, the important parameter for this kind of authorization is `response_type=code`

---

Also, for a security perspective Clients (Web browser) are not supposed to send URI-fragments to servers when they retrieve a document, as [from the specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5). The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the server.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I was making a small mistake as sending the response_type as token instead of code.